# Not able to return the response to index.js file

Tags: node.js

I have added simple git branch function related code in getgitbranches.js file.

Calling this method from index.js.

Facing difficulty in returning branch summary data to index.js file.

**index.js**

```
app.get('/GetGitBranches', (req, res) => {
                var gitBranches
                console.log('inside')
                gitBranches = require('./getgitbranches.js')
                console.log(gitBranches.showlog(req,res))
                res.send(gitBranches.showlog(req,res))

}
```

**getgitbranches.js**

```
let branchSummary = {}
exports.showlog = function (req, res){
    const gitVariable= require('simple-git/promise')()
     var branchVariable=gitVariable.branch(['-r']);
     branchVariable.then(function (data) {
         branchSummary.result = data.all
         giveback(data.all)
     })
}
giveback = function (data){
    //console.log("givaback"+data)
    branchSummary.result =data;
    console.log("Branch Summary Result"+ branchSummary.result)
    return branchSummary.result;
}
```

Comment: Can You show us what have you tried and what was the response you got?

Comment: change this `'` to back ticks(` `) to log ${port}

Comment: @saketh It is working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to log the value which is resolved inside the promise you should either `await` untill the promise is resolved or use callback

***index.js***

```
app.get('/GetGitBranches', async (req, res) => {
      var gitBranches
      console.log('inside')
      gitBranches = require('./getgitbranches.js')
      const response = await gitBranches.showlog(req,res)
      return res.send(response)
}
```

**getGitBranches.js**

```
let branchSummary = {}
exports.showlog = async function (req, res){
    const gitVariable= require('simple-git/promise')()
    const result = await gitVariable.branch(['-r']);
    return giveback(result.all);
}
giveback = function (data){
    //console.log("givaback"+data)
    branchSummary.result =data;
    console.log("Branch Summary Result"+ branchSummary.result)
    return branchSummary.result;
}
```